# Want to designate name of created data frames in for loop

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to remove certain rows from each of my created data frames. I want to perform the same commands on each data frame by using a for loop. I have data frames named participant1, participant2, participant3, ... . Each data frame has the same name with ascending numbers at the end. My code works if I input the name of each individual data frame in it. I just want to create a loop that will do it for all the data frames at once (and maintain every data frame in the process). Each data frame has the same dimensions.

```
lazy = numeric()
for (x in 1:nrow(participant1){
  if (participant1[x, 1] == participant1[x, 3]){
    lazy <- c(lazy, as.numeric(x))
  }else if (participant1[x, 3] == 0){
    lazy <- c(lazy, as.numeric(x))
  }
}
participant1 <- participant1[-(lazy), ]
```

Every place where I have "participant1" I want to be able to substitute it for each data frame I have (participant2, participant3...).

Comment: You can use `assign` `assign("participant1", value = ...)`

Comment: You could also try creating a function to apply to each data.frame